# Behavior of $|f'(z)|/(1+|f(z)|^2)$ as $|z| \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-functions

Let $f(z)$ be an entire holomorphic function in $\mathbb{C}$, and consider the real-valued function
$$g_f(z)=\frac{|f'(z)|}{1+|f(z)|^2}.$$
If $f(z)$ is a polynomial, then it is easy to prove that $\lim_{|z|\rightarrow \infty}g_f(z)=0$.

When $f$ is transcendental, say $f(z)=e^z$, then $g_f(z)=\frac{e^x}{1+e^{2x}}$, which goes to zero when $Re(z)$ is going $\infty$, but remains a constant when $z$ is moving on any vertical line. So far I have not found any example such that the limit goes to zero when $f$ is transcendental.
 **My question** is, can we rigorously prove that there is no transcendental entire function $f$ such that $$
\lim_{|z|\rightarrow \infty}g_f(z)=0\; ?
$$

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/a/78589/116247.

Comment: @MartinR The linked post is great, but does it answer the question?

Comment: @MartinR: But what is not completely clear (to me) from the way this is quoted is if these functions are entire or just meromorphic on a neighborhood of $\infty$.

Comment: The results of Lehto and Virtantan say that $\limsup |z||f'|/(1+|f|^2)\geq 1/2$ for all meromorphic functions, and $=\infty$ for entire functions. The first result is best possible, while the second is not. See my ans.

Comment: @MartinR, the example constructed by Lehto and Virtanen is of the form $F(log z)$, where $F$ is a doubly-period function, with one period equal to $2\pi i$. Hence such function cannot be entire since doubly-period function cannot be entire unless a constant.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is not true. The optimal estimate from below for transcendental entire functions is
$$\limsup_{z\to\infty}\frac{|z||f'(z)|}{\log|z|(1+|f(z)|^2)}=\infty,$$
and this is best possible,

J. Clunie and W. Hayman, The spherical derivative of integral and meromorphic functons, Comment Math. Helv., 40 (1966) 117-148.

More precisely, for every function $\phi(r)\to+\infty$, they constructed an example of transcendental entire function
for which
$$\frac{|z||f'(z)|}{\phi(|z|)\log|z|(1+|f(z)|^2)}$$ is bounded. The function in this example is of the form
$$f(z)=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{z}{2^{k_n}}\right)^{k_n},$$
where $k_n$ is an increasing sequence of integers, which is choosen, depending on $\phi$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm wondering is it possible to have a very concrete example?

Comment: Take $k_n=n$ in the example that I wrote, to make it "concrete".

Answer (score 15):

A concrete example is given by $f(z)=\cos{\sqrt{z}}$. Then
$$
g_f(z) = \frac{|\sin\sqrt{z}|}{2|\sqrt{z}|(1+|\cos^2{\sqrt{z}}|)} .
$$
Obviously, this is small for large $|z|$ if $\sin{\sqrt{z}}$ is not large, and if $\sin\sqrt{z}$ is large, then $|\cos\sqrt{z}|$ is of the same order of magnitude (since $\sin^2 w+\cos^2 w=1$), and again $g_f$ is small.

Comment: $\sqrt{z}$ is discontinuous accross branch cut, and thus not entire.

Comment: @student: $\cos$ is an even function, and therefore $\cos\sqrt z$ is an entire function. If you prefer then you can define it via the power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n z^n/(2n)!$

Comment: @MartinR I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: Very nice! Did you just randomly guess this example, or was there some conceptual insight that led you to it?

Comment: @DanRomik: This may sound strange, but I don't remember very clearly how I got it (so certainly no conceptual insight). I tried for a while to prove the (false) statement, based on the fact that $f(z+w)$, $w\in\mathbb C$ is a normal family.